# How to import .txt data into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import the data from the file at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1leOUk4Z5xp9tTiFLpxgk_7KBv3xwn5eW/view
into a pandas dataframe. I have tried using

```
    data = pd.read_csv('data_engineering_assignment.txt',sep="|")
```

but I got an error saying "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line 231, saw 10"
I dont want to use 'error_bad_lines=False' and skip lines of data.

Kindly help.

Comment: did you check line 231 for what causes the error (why 10 instead of 9 fields are detected, to be more specific)?

Comment: Did you tried to use encoding=

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your dataset, the problem is that sometimes, i find `|` in the  description_text : for example, for this id `5d0c7c4c312ff75188d84954` you have `|`
in `of A|X design`, so pandas considered the second part as a new column (that's why you have the message : `Expected 9 fields, but saw 10`
I hope this will helps you to understand the problem.

Comment: Understood. Any ideas on how I can resolve/clean this data so that I can work with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the columns names, stating that there are 10:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['_id','name','price','website_id','sku','url','brand','media','description_text','other']
dataframe = pd.read_csv('./data_engineering_assignment.txt', names=cols, sep='|' )
dataframe['description_text'] = dataframe['description_text'].map(str) + dataframe['other']
dataframe.to_csv('./data_engineering_assignment_v2.txt', index=False, sep=',')
```

You'll get a warning on memory usage due to pandas having to guess the column data type, but it's ok

Comment: Your solution creates a data frame but pushes some of the description_text into the _id column of the next row. https://imgur.com/a/J8jHFFW Any ideas on how to resolve this? I assume its due to rogue delimiters or empty values at that cell in the column.

Comment: Sure, you may merge the columns back after loading the csv. You can then save the file with a different separator. I've chosen the default ',' in the example, but you may have to pick a different character to avoid falling again into the same problem. Anyway, you can avoid saving and correct the csv every time you load it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6qGPUdt As you can see here the data doesn't go into the 'other' column, it creates a new rows and enters it int he _id column.